# Format output from Custom function(s) within gtsummary table. R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, gtsummary

I would like to create one/two custom functions that call two external functions (weighted_median, weighted_mannwhitney)and whose results are to be formatted with gtsummary table - a working example is shown on the link within the section "The custom function" below. The first external function calculates median (for one variable and does not use grouping variable), while the second external function can use grouping information to calculate p-value

I would like to pass some arguments (see "Arguments to pass" below) to my function so it can perform calculations (see "Calculations to perform" below).

I would then like to pass on to my custom function(s) these arguments so that it builds a table where each row represents each member of the vector of variable names. e.g. for "*ttdeath*" variable currently. But the vector can have many variables  x = c(*age, ttdeath,* ...)

Each row should also have the name of the current variable to be able to identify to which variable the statistics correspond to.

**Arguments to pass:**

1. Dataset name e.g. data = *trial*
2. vector of variable names to be used to build row data as x e.g. x = c(*age, ttdeath*, etc).
3. name of "by" variable to build columns i.e grouping variable e.g. (grp = *response*)
4. weights variable e.g. weights = *marker*

**Calculations to perform:**

5. Then for each of the variables in step 2 (above), I would like to calculate their median for each group variable e.g. *response*(0/1).
6. Then calculate p-value from weighted mannwhitney comparing the two groups

**Desired output**

A gtsummary formatted table (of the results "res_tibble" from each of my input variables (x = c(specified variables)) formatted similar to "Example 2" where the "Characteristic" column corresponds to the variable in argument (step 2 above), "Drug A" and "Drug B" columns correspond to the grouping variable (step 3 above) while the "Overall" column is replaced by "P-Value" (step 6 above)

**Working code for custom function**

See below, its output is "*res_tibble*"

```
# library(sjstats) # avoided to load it for it clashes with sjstats packages on some functions
                               library(gtsummary)
                               library(tidyverse)
                               
                               # x = c(age, ttdeath) # This can be a long list of numeric variables
                               
                               
                               # calculate median for group (response==1)
                               group1 <- subset(trial, response==1)
                               median_grp1 <- sjstats::weighted_median(group1$ttdeath, weights = group1$marker)
                               
                               # calculate median for group (response==0)
                               group2 <- subset(trial, response==0)
                               median_grp2 <- sjstats::weighted_median(group2$ttdeath, weights = group2$marker)
                               
                               # Calculate p-value comparing two groups (grp = response)
                               pval <- sjstats::weighted_mannwhitney(data = trial, x = ttdeath, grp = response, weights = marker)$p.value[[1]]
                               
                               # Combine group medians and p-value for the respective variables e.g. (x = ttdeath)
                               res_tibble <- dplyr::tibble(
                                 median_grp1 = median_grp1,
                                 median_grp2 = median_grp2,
                                 pval = pval
                               )
```

**The custom function**

The custom function e.g. my_custom_function() can then be called within gtsummary table with the arguments mentioned above and its output formatted by gtsummary as below (does not work)
Inspiring and working example here ("Example 2" table): [Working gtsummary example](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_custom_summary.html)

```
                               tbl_custom_summary_ex2 <-
                                 trial %>%
                                 tbl_custom_summary(
                                   include = c("age", "ttdeath"),
                                   by = "response",
                                   stat_fns = ~ my_custom_function,
                                   ...
                                 )
```

How can I do this? [Example Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySVf7.png)

Comment: where/what is `my_custom_function()`

Comment: apologies for delayed response! That means that I want to create my own custom function, for which I can use with gtsummary. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: ok can you provide an example function so that it is possible to troubleshoot further?

Comment: @Mike Sure. Please see the example custom functions "my_stats", "mean_ci" and "diff_to_great_mean" which are later passed on to gtsummary table as e.g. "stat_fns = everything() ~ my_stats" for the first, "stat_fns = ~ mean_ci" for the second and "stat_fns = ~ diff_to_great_mean" for the third here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_custom_summary.html#examples